# Transforming time-type variables for calculation in R

Tags: r, time, transform

I have a matrix of time variables in the following format.

```
  time <- matrix(c('01:11', '01:20', '00:51', '01:09',            
          '01:11', '01:00', '01:19', '00:14', 
          '00:57', '01:12', '01:14', '00:43', 
          '01:10', '01:19', '01:03', '00:27', 
          '00:59', '01:04', '00:46', '00:52', 
          '01:05', '01:13', '01:01', '00:48'), ncol=3)
```

Where the values before ':' are minutes and after that are seconds. 
I want to convert all the values into seconds. But I am not sure how I should transform the data so that those values with minutes can be converted into seconds, and those already in seconds can then be used as a numeric value.

I tried with the chron package my dataset seems to be in the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strsplit` with apply. If the values are not `character`, you may want to convert it to `character`.

```
apply(time, 2, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x,":"), function(y)
                         as.numeric(y[1])*60 + as.numeric(y[2])))
```